# Align flex children to top

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I get flexbox children to line up vertically to the top edge of each row?

HTML:

```css
#container {
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.child {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
}
img, h3 {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOBzOp

What I see is [image: this] but I want it to look like 
[image: this]

Comment: Just remove the `margin: auto` from the `.child` because you don't need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `margin:auto` of `.child` to `margin: 0px auto`.

Answer (score 2):

Give `justify-content: space-around;` to `#container` id instead of `justify-content: space-between;` and remove `margin: auto;` to `.child` class.

```css
#container {
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.child { 
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
}
img, h3 {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be changing `margin: auto;` to `margin: 0 auto;` this will prevent the box auto centralize vertically but retaining its horizontal alignment, like so:

```
.child {
    border: 1px dotted #CCC;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I also want the same, and most solutions didn't work for me.**

I implemented this way.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 300px;
  gap: 10px
}

.box div{
    border: 1px solid red;
}



<div class="box">
  <div>Hello Stackoverflow</div>
  <div>I am top align</div>
  <div>Three
    <br>has
    <br>extra
    <br>text
  </div>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can try like

```
.child {
    vertical-align: baseline; //either of them
    margin: 0px auto; // any one
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read up on which properties work with flex items...`vertical-align` is not one of them

Comment: I don't have to, I know the `margin: 0px auto;` work and `vertical-align: baseline;` does not...and I didn't down voted, instead I tried to be helpful, with my first comment, so you could fix the answer before getting down votes.